# Vector of vectors, heap versus stack (C++)

Tags: c++, vector

I wanted to initialize a vector of vectors that contain pointers to Courses.  I declared this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Course*> > *CSPlan = 
        new std::vector<std::vector<Course*> >(smsNum);
```

What I wanted to do by this is to have a vector of vectors, each inside vector is a vector that contains pointers to Courses, and I wanted the MAIN vector to be of size `int smsNum`.    Furthermore, I wanted it on the heap.

My questions are:

1. Are both the main vector AND the inside vectors allocated on the heap? or is it only the MAIN vector is on the heap and its' indexes are pointers to other smaller vectors on the stack?
2. I declared it to be of size `int smsNum` so the Main vector is of size 10, but what about the smaller vectors? are they also of that size or are they still dynamic?

My goal in the end is to have a vector of vectors, both the Main vector and the child vectors on the heap, and ONLY the Main vector is of size smsNum, while the rest are dynamic.

Comment: Why the use of pointers here? They make the code more complicated and chances are, you don’t need them.

Comment: I do need them because I want to store this CSPlan to a Computer Science Student as a member field, and do operations on it in certain situations.

Comment: For that description, you still don't need pointers.

Comment: That’s no reason to use pointers.

Comment: I dont understand. I want this CSPlan vector of vectors to be on the heap, therefore, the use of "new" is a must. Therefore, I must have a pointer pointing to it. And when later I want to assign CSPlan to a student, I will have to send this pointer!

Comment: I could be wrong. What is the other way? I want each student to have a CSPlan of his own. But how can I allocate a CSPlan on the heap and send it to each student as a member field?
I discovered (from my stupidity) that ALL CS students have same CSPlan, causing me out_of_range stuff.
Whats the good solution?

Comment: The vector structure is dynamically allocated  already, you don't need any pointers to force such allocation whatsoever. The allocation is performed by the stl methods, that constructs your vector. The variable that references the vector is statically allocated, but the contents of the vector are all allocated on the heap.

Comment: It is highly doubtful the top-level pointer is required. I can buy the inner Course pointer. It is not uncommon to build vectors of pointers (raw or smart) to do things like sort *addresses* without modifying the data they point to), but based on your described usage the top-level pointer is likely *not necessary*. Make your member variable *the vector*; not a pointer to it.

Comment: I see!
Thanks!!
Will test it in a bit!

Comment: I've added a complement to my answer, so that it may clarifies this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any structure that can grow as large as the user wants it to is going to be allocated on the heap. The memory stack, on the other hand, is used to allocate statically allocated variables, that the program has control of the size statically, during the compilation process.

Since you can have a loop like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < your_value; i++) {
    vector.insert(...);
}
```

And considering `your_value` as an integer read from the standard input, the compiler have no control on how large will be your vector, i.e., it does not know what is the maximum amount of inserts you may perform.

To solve this, the structure must be allocated on the heap, where it may grow as large as the OS allows it to -- considering primary memory, and swap. As a complement, if you use the pointer to the vector, you'll be simply dynamically allocating a variable to reference the vector. This changes **NOT** the fact that the contents of the vector is, necessarily, being allocated on the heap.

You'll have, in your stack:

- a variable "x" that stores the address of a variable "y";

And in your heap:

- the value of the variable "y", that is a reference to your vector of vectors;
- the contents of your vector of vectors (accessed by "y", that is accessed by "x").